# Using a Scala 3 Library in a Scala 2.13 Project

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

I try to use my Scala 3 Library in my Scala 2.13 Project.

I get the following exception:

```
(class scala.tools.tasty.UnpickleException/TASTy signature has wrong version.
 expected: {majorVersion: 28, minorVersion: 0}
 found   : {majorVersion: 28, minorVersion: 1}
```

The library uses *Scala 3.1*. The Project uses *Scala 2.13.6*, with this dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += ("io.github.pme123" %% "camundala-api" % "0.1.6").cross(CrossVersion.for2_13Use3)
```

How can I resolve this? I could not find a Compatibility Matrix. My guess is that when using *Scala 3.0.* in the library it would work.

Comment: I think you have to upgrade to 2.13.7.

Comment: @Jasper-M thanks that works - do you know where this is documented?

Comment: No sorry I don't know. I think the release notes of the relevant Scala versions make mention of this. But don't know if or where you can find a compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jasper-M, the **TASTy** **reader** was updated in Scala **2.13.7** to work with Scala **3.1**. [Here is the release note](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.7) where it was mentioned.

So:

- Scala 2.13.7 works with Scala 3.1
- Scala 2.13.6 works with Scala 3.0